# action script 2 - asking for input text and send to a link according to answer

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-2

I would like to make an input text field in flash as2. what i need is when the user write down an answer it will direct him to an html page i created.. there are 3 answers and 3 pages,
so they will write down one of the answer and when they will click "enter" they will be redirected.

I understand you can do it with "if" statement but i don't know how!

thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be like this:

```
submitBTN.onRelease = function() {
    switch (_root.inputfield.text) {
        case "first answer" :
            getURL("firstpage.html", "_self");
            break;
        case "second answer" :
            getURL("secondpage.html", "_self");
            break;
        case "third answer" :
            getURL("thirdpage.html", "_self");
            break;
    }
};
```